# Intento ingresar un registro, pero me devuelve un error

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Intento ingresar un registro, pero me devuelve un error

Este es el codigo del metodo

```
const createUser = async (req, res) => {
const {cedula, nombres, apellidos, email, password, tipo} = req.body

try {
    const response = await pool.query('INSERT INTO public.usuario (cedulausuario, nombreusuario, apellidousuario, email, password, estado, fechacreacion, tipousuario) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, 1, CURRENT_DATE, $6)', [cedula, nombres, apellidos, email, password, tipo]);
res.status(200).send({ mensaje: 'OK-nuevo-usuario', estado: 'USUARIO REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE' })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).send({ mensaje: 'NO-nuevo-usuario' })
}
};
```

Este es el mensasje de error que se muestra al hacer la insercion mediante postman

```
    {
  length: 359,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23502',
  detail: 'La fila que falla contiene (null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2021-09-01 00:00:00+00, null).',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'usuario',
  column: 'cedulausuario',
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'd:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\executor\\execmain.c',
  line: '1953',
  routine: 'ExecConstraints'
}
```

Y esta es la imagen del postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te has fijado si los datos que sacas (o intentas sacar) del cuerpo (*body*) de la solicitud, realmente están allí? Basta con hacer un `console.log(req.body);` para darte cuenta lo que estás recibiendo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no hallas configurado.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

lo cual te permite leer datos desde formularios en express.