# Error Insertar datos con node a postgres La fila que falla contiene (null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2021-09-01 00:00:00+00, null)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, express

Intento insertar registros a una tabla en postgres a travez de postman pero me da un error de datos null, este es el metodo de insercion

```
async function createUser (req, res)  {
    const {cedula, nombres, apellidos, email, password, tipo} = req.body

    try {
        const response = await pool.query('INSERT INTO public.usuario (cedulausuario, nombreusuario, apellidousuario, email, password, estado, fechacreacion, tipousuario) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, 1, CURRENT_DATE, $6)', [cedula, nombres, apellidos, email, password, tipo]);
    res.status(200).send({ mensaje: 'OK-nuevo-usuario', estado: 'USUARIO REGISTRADO CORRECTAMENTE' })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({ mensaje: 'NO-nuevo-usuario' })
    }
    
};
```

y este es el error que me devuelve al pasar los datos mediante postman

```
{
  length: 359,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23502',
  detail: 'La fila que falla contiene (null, null, null, null, null, 1, 2021-09-01 00:00:00+00, null).',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'usuario',
  column: 'cedulausuario',
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'd:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\executor\\execmain.c',
  line: '1953',
  routine: 'ExecConstraints'
}
```

y de la siguiente manera paso los datos mediante postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es lo que esta mal en el codigo por que me devuelve un error que estoy enviando datos null

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Intento ingresar un registro, pero me devuelve un error](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/480654/intento-ingresar-un-registro-pero-me-devuelve-un-error)

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas, no es la forma de usar el sitio. Si tienes que agregar detalles, edita la pregunta original. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema, no existia problema alguno en el codigo, pero recomendaria revisar los inyectores de peticiones, en mi caso postman no me estaba enviando en formato JSON lo que hacia que me salgan datos null, solo cambie el header a aplicaction/json y el envio se hizo correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.